# How to update Facebook user picture from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

How to update user picture (avatar) for user's Facebook account from an iOS app?

Is there a way to achieve this using Facebook SDK, or Graph API or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There's no ability for a platform app to change the user's profile picture.